# Cannot compile Go language on Mac OS X 10.6.7

Tags: go

When following instructions on [Getting Started - The Go Programming Language](http://golang.org/doc/install.html), I get the code and try to run the `all.bash` script.

But I get this error after a lot of other successful looking output:

```
INSTALL FAIL net
CGOPKGPATH= cgo --  cgo_bsd.go cgo_unix.go 
touch _obj/_cgo_run
6g  -o _go_.6 dial.go dnsmsg.go fd_darwin.go hosts.go ip.go ipsock.go iprawsock.go lookup.go net.go parse.go pipe.go sock.go tcpsock.go udpsock.go unixsock.go  newpollserver.go fd.go file.go dnsconfig.go dnsclient.go port.go  _obj/cgo_bsd.cgo1.go _obj/cgo_unix.cgo1.go _obj/_cgo_gotypes.go
6c -FVw -I/Users/matryer/Work/go/pkg/darwin_amd64 -I . -o "_cgo_defun.6" _obj/_cgo_defun.c
gcc -m64 -I . -g -fPIC -O2 -o _cgo_main.o -c   _obj/_cgo_main.c
gcc -m64 -I . -g -fPIC -O2 -o cgo_bsd.cgo2.o -c   _obj/cgo_bsd.cgo2.c
gcc -m64 -I . -g -fPIC -O2 -o cgo_unix.cgo2.o -c   _obj/cgo_unix.cgo2.c
gcc -m64 -I . -g -fPIC -O2 -o _cgo_export.o -c   _obj/_cgo_export.c
gcc -m64 -g -fPIC -O2 -o _cgo1_.o _cgo_main.o cgo_bsd.cgo2.o cgo_unix.cgo2.o _cgo_export.o  
cgo -dynimport _cgo1_.o >_obj/_cgo_import.c_ && mv -f _obj/_cgo_import.c_ _obj/_cgo_import.c
6c -FVw -I . -o "_cgo_import.6" _obj/_cgo_import.c
cgo_bsd.go:5[_obj/cgo_bsd.cgo1.go:8]: undefined: _Cconst_AI_MASK
cgo_unix.go:69[_obj/cgo_unix.cgo1.go:72]: undefined: _Cconst_AI_ALL
cgo_unix.go:69[_obj/cgo_unix.cgo1.go:72]: undefined: _Cconst_AI_V4MAPPED
cgo_unix.go:69[_obj/cgo_unix.cgo1.go:72]: undefined: _Cconst_AI_CANONNAME
make[1]: *** [_go_.6] Error 1
make: *** [net.install] Error 1
```

Has anybody else seen this and fixed it?

I am running Snow Leopard (10.6.7) build `10J869`.

Comment: You might want to try installing from MacPorts.

Comment: Which version of Go? You may want to try earlier or later versions of it.

Comment: I have SL 10.6.7, tried with source installation, macports and HomeBrew, same result;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an open issue, relating to a new version of Xcode, for OS X 10.7 and 10.6.7.

[Issue 1881](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=1881): cgo const error on OS X 10.7

NOTE: [Revision 142f0bc0d6e7](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=142f0bc0d6e7) has been made to close [issue 1881](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=1881). To update Go for all changes up to and including this revision, run:

```
$ cd $GOROOT/src
$ hg pull
$ hg update 142f0bc0d6e7
$ ./all.bash
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate exactly which version of Go you are building.  Note that it is a dynamic project where the versions change frequently.

I just ran `hg pull` and `hg update` in a directory where I've previously compiled Go successfully (on MacOS X 10.6.7).  Then I ran `sh all.bash` and I didn't see any issues during the build or test phases (though it takes longer to build now than it did when Go was first announced).

FWIW, `hg tags` gives me:

```
tip                             8715:599657138e00
weekly.2011-06-09               8703:c81944152e97
weekly                          8703:c81944152e97
weekly.2011-06-02               8623:3418f22c39eb
weekly.2011-05-22               8483:c98449d685d2
release.r57.1                   8294:95d2ce135523
```

And the end of the build cycle gives:

```
--- cd ../test
0 known bugs; 0 unexpected bugs

ALL TESTS PASSED

---
Installed Go for darwin/amd64 in /Users/jleffler/go.
Installed commands in /Users/jleffler/bin.
The compiler is 6g.
```

---

#### Therefore...

There is a chance that if you change the version of Go (possibly to a more recent one), then it will work for you, too.

---

And, another FWIW or FYI, I redid the build on a different machine also running MacOS X 10.6.7 this afternoon, and the tip version is slightly different, and there are apparently 2 known bugs.

```
--- cd ../test
2 known bugs; 0 unexpected bugs

ALL TESTS PASSED

---
Installed Go for darwin/amd64 in /Users/jleffler/External-Source-Repositories/hg/go.
Installed commands in /Users/jleffler/External-Source-Repositories/hg/go/bin.
*** You need to add /Users/jleffler/External-Source-Repositories/hg/go/bin to your $PATH. ***
The compiler is 6g.

On OS X the debuggers must be installed setgrp procmod.
Read and run ./sudo.bash to install the debuggers.

real    4m55.695s
user    2m52.436s
sys     1m10.222s
Osiris-9 JL: hg tags | sed 15q
tip                             8716:164ef168486b
weekly.2011-06-09               8703:c81944152e97
weekly                          8703:c81944152e97
weekly.2011-06-02               8623:3418f22c39eb
weekly.2011-05-22               8483:c98449d685d2
release.r57.1                   8294:95d2ce135523
```

The timing information (just under 5 minutes for the build and test cycle) is from running:

```
time all.bash
```

Comment: And this is an answer to the question … why? If you’re saying it works for you, do it in a comment to the question.

Comment: @Kissaki: it is evidence that there is a (very recent) version of Go that can be compiled on MacOS X 10.6.7, so one solution to the OP's problem might be to change the version of Go that they are compiling.

Comment: I understand that, but that was not written in the answer. It was just a statement it runs for you.